# Is there a function to group letters that occur more than once in array using php

Tags: php

I have an array as `$arr = {"a","b","b","c","c","c"}`

Is there a PHP function that will return `{"a","b","c"}`

Comment: `{"a","b","c"}` is not a php array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, we have `array_unique()` to remove any duplicates from an array. Please keep in mind, you can write a PHP array with `array()` or `[]` and not with `{}`.

So in your case:

```php
$array = ["a","b","b","c","c","c"];
$new_array = array_unique($array); // returns ['a', 'b', 'c'];
```

Read more about it [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

Comment: Yes I know, using {} was a mistake on my path, Thank you for your help